# Unknown Issue with segmentation fault and linked lists

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

So I am trying to program a mechanical program. 
The program is long but here are the functions that are causing me problems: `recherche_noe` and `creation_noe`. No need to bother with the rest.

It's in french so bear with me but the idea is this: first in the `main` I ask the user the number of `noe` in `lst_noe` (which is a list of `noe`). With `creation_noe` he makes that while asking the user for info for the structure. Finally `recherche_noe` returns the `noe` that I am looking for. All the info is stored in `struct maillage` which you have other structures inside. Thank you for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



/*==============================================*/
/*     Déclaration des structures    */
/*==============================================*/

struct matrice
{
    char nom[20];
    int n,m;
    double **tab;
    struct  matrice *next;
};

struct element
{
    int num;
    int n1, n2;
    double k;
    struct element *next;
};

struct noeud
{
    int num;
    double u;
    double f;
    struct noeud *next;
};

struct maillage
{
    int nb_noe, nb_elt;
    struct noeud *lst_noe;
    struct element *lst_elt;
    struct matrice *K, *U, *F;
};

typedef struct matrice* matrices;
typedef struct element* elements;
typedef struct noeud* noeuds;
typedef struct maillage* maillages;
char buffer[100];


/*==============================================*/
/*               Recherche       */
/*==============================================*/

noeuds recherche_noe(maillages mail,int num){
    int i;
    maillages temp=mail;

    while(temp->lst_noe!=NULL){

        if(temp->lst_noe->num == num)
            return temp;
        temp->lst_noe=temp->lst_noe->next;
    }
    printf("Le noeud recherche n'existe pas");
    return temp;
}

elements recherche_elt(maillages mail,int num){
    int i;
    maillages temp=mail;

    while(temp->lst_elt->num != num /*&& temp->lst_elt->next!=NULL*/){
        temp->lst_elt=temp->lst_elt->next;
    }
    if(temp->lst_elt->num != num /*&& temp->lst_elt->next==NULL*/){
        printf("L'element recherche n'existe pas");
    }else{
        return mail->lst_elt;
    }
}


/*==============================================*/
/*                   creation                   */
/*==============================================*/



matrices creation_noeud(maillages mail){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<mail->nb_noe;i++){
        noeuds new = (noeuds)malloc(sizeof(struct noeud));
        new->num = i+1;
        printf("Deplacement du noeud %d: ",i+1);
        buffer[0]='\0';
        getchar();  //reinitialisation de buffer
        scanf("%[^\n]",buffer);
        if((int) strlen(buffer)){    //si la taille du buffer différente 0
            new->u= (double)atof(buffer);
        }
        else{
            printf("Donner l'effort %d du noeuds",i+1);
            scanf("%lf", &new->f);
        }
        new->next=mail->lst_noe;
        mail->lst_noe=new;
    }
}

void creation_element(maillages mail)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<mail->nb_elt;i++){
        elements new= (elements)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
        new->num=i+1;
        printf("Donner le noeud 1 de l'element %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d", &new->n1);
        printf("Donner le noeud 2 de l'element %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d", &new->n2);
        printf("Donner la raideur de l'element %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%lf",&new->k);
        new->next= mail->lst_elt;
        mail->lst_elt=new;
    }
}


matrices creation_mat(int n,int m, char *nom){
    int i,j;
    matrices new=(matrices)malloc(sizeof(struct matrice));
    strcpy(new->nom,nom);
    new->n = n;
    new->m = m;
    new->tab = (double**)malloc((n)*sizeof(double*));
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        new->tab[i] = (double*)malloc((n)*sizeof(double));
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)      /* mise a zero des composantes */
        for (j=0;j<m;j++)
            new->tab[i][j] =0;

    return new;
}


/*==============================================*/
/*               Assemblage          */
/*==============================================*/


void assemblage(maillages mail){
    int a,b,i,j,k;

    mail->K = creation_mat(mail->nb_noe, mail->nb_noe,"K");
    mail->U = creation_mat(mail->nb_noe, 1,"U");



    for (j=0; j<mail->nb_noe; j++){ //Initialisation de K
            for(k=0; k<mail->nb_noe; k++){
                mail->K->tab[j][k]=0;
            }
    }
    printf("%d",recherche_elt(mail,i+1)->n1);
    for (i=0; i<mail->nb_elt; i++){ // Assemblage matrice K

        a = recherche_elt(mail,i+1)->n1-1;
        b = recherche_elt(mail,i+1)->n2-1;
        mail->K->tab[a][a] +=recherche_elt(mail,i+1)->k;
        mail->K->tab[a][b] -=recherche_elt(mail,i+1)->k;
        mail->K->tab[b][a] -=recherche_elt(mail,i+1)->k;
        mail->K->tab[b][b] +=recherche_elt(mail,i+1)->k;

    }


    for (i=0; i<mail->nb_noe; i++){ // Assemblage matrice U
        mail->U->tab[i][0] = recherche_noe(mail,i+1)->u;
    }
}

/*==============================================*/
/*               Produit                */
/*==============================================*/


matrices produit(matrices mat1,matrices mat2,char *nom){
    int i,j,k;
    matrices prod;
    if(mat1->m!=mat2->n){
        printf("Erreur, les matrices ne sont pas compatibles\n\n");
    }else{
        prod=malloc(sizeof(struct matrice));
        strcpy(prod->nom,nom);
        prod->next=NULL;
        prod->n=mat1->n;
        prod->m=mat2->m;
        prod->tab= (double **)malloc(prod->n * sizeof(double *));
        for (i=0; i<prod->n; i++)
            prod->tab[i] = (double *)malloc(prod->m * sizeof(double));

        for (i=0;i<prod->n;i++){
            for (j=0;j<prod->m;j++){
                prod->tab[i][j]=0;
                for (k=0;k<mat1->m;k++){
                    prod->tab[i][j]+=mat1->tab[i][k] * mat2->tab[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return prod;
    }
}

/*==============================================*/
/*               Affichage                */
/*==============================================*/



void affiche_mat(matrices mats){
    int i,j;
    printf("Matrice %s de dimensions %d*%d:\n",mats->nom,mats->n,mats->m);
    for (i=0;i<mats->n;i++){
        for (j=0;j<mats->m;j++){
            printf("%s[%d][%d]: %lf\n",mats->nom,i,j,mats->tab[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}















int main(){
    int i;
    elements lst_elt;
    noeuds lst_noe;
    maillages mail=malloc(sizeof(struct maillage));
    mail->lst_noe=NULL;
    mail->lst_elt=NULL;


    printf("Donner le nombre de noeuds voulu: ");
    scanf("%d",&mail->nb_noe);
    printf("Donner le nombre d'elements voulu: ");
    scanf("%d",&mail->nb_elt);
    creation_noeud(mail);
    creation_element(mail);


    printf("%d",recherche_elt(mail,2+1)->n1+45);

    assemblage (mail);

    produit(mail->K,mail->U,"F");

    /*affiche_mat(mail->K);
    printf("\n");
    affiche_mat(mail->U);
    printf("\n");
    affiche_mat(mail->F);
    printf("\n");*/





}
```

Comment: copy/paste error:: `new->tab[i] = (double*)malloc((n)*sizeof(double));` **-->>**  `new->tab[i] = (double*)malloc((m)*sizeof(double));` (or the other way round) [And, IMHO you should remove the casts and the silly typedefs]

Comment: Thank you for spoting that mistake out. But that doesn't solve my main problem with the list of noe. Why doesn't the printf in the main work correctly (source of the seg fault). i traced it back to recherche_noe.

Comment: Also, you forgot to initialise and zero the new matrix in product(). And your linked-list code  is cumbersome.

Comment: The zeroing of th ematrix is done when it is created, in creation_mat. And yeah i am sorry about that all of this is basically self taught the teacher is useless. That's why i am still having some problems with the linked lists.

Comment: in produit(): `prod=malloc(sizeof(struct matrice));` That's where functions are for. And `malloc()` does **not** zero the returned memory.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right i apologies.

Comment: and btw recherche noe doesnt return the number but the noe itself and with the ->num i get the number. i explained myself badly in th edescription

Comment: Also, your `->lst_elt` is a kind of cursor inside the node ,and you seem to fail to resetit. [voting to close: hire a programmer, or use a debugger]

Answer (score 0):

When walking the linked list, you are altering the contents of the linked list, instead of advancing the temp.

---

```
elements recherche_elt(maillages mail,int num){
    elements temp;

    for (temp = mail->lst_elt; temp; temp = temp->next ) {
        if (temp->num == num) return temp;
    }
    printf("L'element recherche n'existe pas\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

---

And, after removal of the typedefs, it becomes:

---

```
struct element *recherche_elt(struct maillage *mail,int num){
    struct element *this;

    for (this = mail->lst_elt; this; this = this->next ) {
        if (this->num == num) return this;
    }
    printf("L'element recherche n'existe pas\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

---

[The same kind of error is reproduced at other places in the code]

Comment: Yes i am aware that the problem is in a lot of places. I am organized in my disorder. But i f i manage to fix the recherche_noe problem i'll be able to fix the rest. 
just know that this is not the final version at all and that i am not a programmer that's why for one there are mistakes and for second i do not have the right reflexes for correct syntaxe. I am a mechanical engineering student