# Absolutely can't see what causes a segmentation fault even after 2 whole days

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

The problem is with the printf in the main. I am not a programmer and this is a bit self taught so don't butcher me. The function creation_noe creates a linked list of noes. If we want 3 of them then the link will start with the one numbered as 3, but the printf in the main gives me 1 3 3. I am lost.
Thank you for your help.

PS: the program is a lot longer this is only the needed part. in case you have question I am here to answer them. I just don't want you to waste your time on the rest which is irrelevant. thanks

P.P.S: The terms are in French

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    
struct matrice
{
    char nom[20];
    int n,m;
    double **tab;
    struct  matrice *next;
};


struct element
    {
        int num;
        int n1, n2;
        double k;
        struct element *next;
    };
    
    struct noeud
    {
        int num;
        double u;
        double f;
        struct noeud *next;
    };
    
    struct maillage
    {
        int nb_noe, nb_elt;
        struct noeud *lst_noe;
        struct element *lst_elt;
        struct matrice *K, *U, *F;
    };
    
    typedef struct element* elements;
    typedef struct noeud* noeuds;
    typedef struct maillage* maillages;
    
    
    /*==============================================*/
    /*               Recherche       */
    /*==============================================*/
    
    noeuds recherche_noe(maillages mail,int num){
        int i;
        maillages temp=mail;
        printf("%d %d ",num,mail->lst_noe->num);
    
        while((temp->lst_noe!=NULL) && (temp->lst_noe->num!=num)){
            temp->lst_noe=temp->lst_noe->next;
        }
        if(temp->lst_noe->num==num){
            return temp->lst_noe;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    
    /*==============================================*/
    /*                   creation                   */
    /*==============================================*/
    
    
    
    void creation_noeud(maillages mail){
        int i;
        noeuds new = (noeuds)malloc(sizeof(struct noeud));
        mail->lst_noe=NULL;
    
        for (i=0;i<mail->nb_noe;i++){
            new->num = i+1;
            printf("Deplacement du noeud %d: ",new->num);
            scanf("%lf", &new->u);
    
    
    
    
            new->next=mail->lst_noe;
            mail->lst_noe=new;
        }
    }
    
    int main(){
        int i;
        maillages mail=malloc(sizeof(struct maillage));
    
        printf("Donner le nombre de noeuds voulu: ");
        scanf("%d",&mail->nb_noe);
        printf("Donner le nombre d'elements voulu: ");
        scanf("%d",&mail->nb_elt);
        creation_noeud(mail);
        //creation_element(mail);
        printf("aaa %d %d %d aaa \n",1,mail->lst_noe->num,mail->lst_noe->next->num,mail->lst_noe->next->next->num);
    }
```

Comment: You absolutely need to learn how to debug your own programs. It will save you countless hours of just looking at your code wondering what is wrong with it. Absolutely. Definitely. Under no uncertain terms. Learn how to debug.

Comment: first off all never alas (typedef) the pointers as the code is difficult to read and write as you cont see if something is the pointer or not.

Comment: @bolov is right, you should have a look to gdb documentation https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50436538

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mail->lst_noe=NULL;

...

new->next=mail->lst_noe;
mail->lst_noe=new;


and then

mail->lst_noe->next->next->num
```

This is bound to give segfault as `mail->lst_noe->next` is nothing but `mail->lst_noe` which itself is `NULL`. Dereferencing a null pointer gives you SEGFAULT.

Comment: i do know how to debug but i just can't fing it. The thing is our teacher gave us an example, and i used the exact same logic as his. He doesnt teach us much though. Nevertheless i did exactly as he did. When you create a pointer for a list should'nt you start by pointing it to NULL? then start linking fom there. Bcause i can't see why         mail->lst_noe->next      is nothing

Comment: If for example i make nb_noe=3, then  mail->lst_noe->next->num=2, No?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using a tool to identify the problem in the future.

Valgrind is good for catching memory errors. You compile your program with debug flags (the -g option) and then run 

`valgrind ./<myprogram>`

You will need to have installed valgrind.

Also if you use the clang compiler you can use the `-fsanitize=memory` compiler option.

Both of these techniques will tell you the line of code that causes the memory error.

Comment: I apologize but man you lost me. I am a mechanical engineering student so coding is not really my forte. I do not know the syntaxe you used. If you could please just tell me why isn't my linking working correctly. it's supposed to print 3 2 1 with the printf in the main but it doesn't and prints 1 3 3 . To be honest i for me the logic is perfect there. i used the example of the teacher. yet still not working...